# UIPicker to open to a UIView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I have a UIPicker that is holding titles. I would like it to when a row is tapped to open to a .xib view/ UIView and have a small textview in it. Is this possable?? If so please help!!

Thanks in advance for any help..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but it is possible.

When a UIPickerView has a row tapped, it tells its delegate via the `-pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` method.

So, you'll need to set the picker's delegate. You do this by dragging from the delegate outlet to your controller in Interface Builder, or by setting `picker.delegate = someObject` in code.
[setting delegate http://grab.by/zlY](http://grab.by/zlY)

Then, in the delegate:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // load xib or whatever you like
}
```

**Edit** with more info:

To load the XIB you will most likely want to use `-initWithNibNamed:bundle:` on a view controller class. In that delegate function above, the number `row` is the row which was selected. You can use that row to construct the nib name you want to use.

Comment: Ok Awesome...man thanks!! although im still pretty new I follow you but like where i load the xib   how do i need to call this function and tell witch row xib to load up?? I have messed aroung with tablw view and have them working mostly from tuts but still dragging my feet trying to learn.   Thanks for help thus far!!